# Delete TeamCity Build Logs

Tags: teamcity

A TeamCity job is currently failing because there is insufficient space on the disk. Via Administration => Disk usage, I found out that there are an exorbitant amount of build logs:

[image: Disk usage]

I have tried cleaning up the build history via the TeamCity UI, deleting everything before the last 10 successful builds, but this at best freed up 500 MB of disk space (thousands of builds have been created over a span of 2 years). I want to see on the disk where these files are located, and ideally, delete any and all log files safely, thus, nothing is broken afterwards. I have tried navigating through the TeamCity file structure, but am simply lost.

Comment: Do you use external database to store build artifacts and logs?

Comment: Try the utility: https://windirstat.net/  Just point it at the problem drive and drill into each directory until you find what you need.  It's pretty easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can locate internally stored build log files in the [TeamCity Data Directory](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/TeamCity+Data+Directory#TeamCityDataDirectory-StructureofTeamCityDataDirectory), under
`<TeamCity Data Directory>\system\artifacts\<project ID>\<build configuration name>\<internal_build_id>\.teamcity\logs`.

If you delete the files under the directory, the corresponding build will not have build log and problems/test failure details.